# REACT JS: Map over an array of objects to render in JSX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, reactjs

I am new to React JS The question is that I need to display all the fields from my database in this piece of code. I have been able to obtain all the data as objects in the browser console and I am able to view the last piece of data in the array in the browser but have not been able to view them. Please forgive me for the wrong format in the code as I am new to this.Thanks in advance.....

Output and Codes

Browser View:
Land of Toys Inc. is the name 131 is the ID

The JSON data :

```
{"posts":[
  {"id":"103","name":"Atelier graphique"},
  {"id":"112","name":"Signal Gift Stores"},
  {"id":"114","name":"Australian Collectors, Co."},
  {"id":"119","name":"La Rochelle Gifts"},
  {"id":"121","name":"Baane Mini Imports"},
  {"id":"124","name":"Mini Gifts Distributors Ltd."},
  {"id":"125","name":"Havel & Zbyszek Co"},
  {"id":"128","name":"Blauer See Auto, Co."},
  {"id":"129","name":"Mini Wheels Co."},
  {"id":"131","name":"Land of Toys Inc."}
]}
```

This data is obtained through a PHP code written as a plugin which is in the form of a url which is given in the JS code

http://localhost/Akshay/REACT/testDataAPI.php?user=2&num=10&format=json

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React Tutorial</title>
    <!-- Not present in the tutorial. Just for basic styling. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" />
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.0/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/jquery@3.1.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/remarkable@1.6.2/dist/remarkable.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">


var UserGist = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {

      username:[],
      companyID:[]
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() 
  {

    var rows = [];

   this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {

      for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) 
      {
            var lastGist = result.posts[i];
            //console.log(result.posts[i]);
            this.setState({
            username: lastGist.id,
            companyID: lastGist.name
            });
      }

     }.bind(this));

  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  render: function() {
            return (
        <li>{this.state.companyID} is the name {this.state.username} is the ID</li>
        );

  }
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <UserGist source="http://localhost/Akshay/REACT/testDataAPI.php?user=2&num=10&format=json" />,
  document.getElementById('content')
); 

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use map to render your data. and store the json as a javascript object in the state itself instead of two seperate arrays.

```
 <!-- Not present in the tutorial. Just for basic styling. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" />
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.0/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/jquery@3.1.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/remarkable@1.6.2/dist/remarkable.min.js"></script>
    <div id="content"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">


var UserGist = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {

     data: [{"id":"103","name":"Atelier graphique"},
  {"id":"112","name":"Signal Gift Stores"},
  {"id":"114","name":"Australian Collectors, Co."},
  {"id":"119","name":"La Rochelle Gifts"},
  {"id":"121","name":"Baane Mini Imports"},
  {"id":"124","name":"Mini Gifts Distributors Ltd."},
  {"id":"125","name":"Havel & Zbyszek Co"},
  {"id":"128","name":"Blauer See Auto, Co."},
  {"id":"129","name":"Mini Wheels Co."},
  {"id":"131","name":"Land of Toys Inc."}]
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() 
  {

  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  render: function() {
            return (
            <div>
        {this.state.data.map(function(item, index){
          return    <li>{item.name} is the company name, {item.id} is the ID</li>

        })}</div>
        );

  }
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <UserGist source="http://localhost/Akshay/REACT/testDataAPI.php?user=2&num=10&format=json" />,
  document.getElementById('content')
); 

    </script>
</html>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wrjr2zet/)**

For the fiddle example I have deleted your `$.get()` code in `componentDidMount`.

> P.S. Create the state array data as an array of object as shown in the
>   fiddle example

Comment: I tried to use map to render it  but its created an error saying it is undefined will cheak out your solution and get back to you thanks for the help

Comment: @AkshayVenugopal what is giving undefined

Comment: It works but I need to use this like an API so how should i proceed about that here the JSON data is given in the code i need to use it from a batabase like phpmyadmin

Comment: Also a warning popped up

Comment: "Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `UserGist`.
    in li (created by UserGist)
    in UserGist"

Comment: You can get over with this warning simply by adding a key as ` <li key={index}>{item.name} is the company name, {item.id} is the ID</li>`

Comment: What you should do is that fetch the data from the server and then push it as an object into the state variable. For the fiddle example I just copied the sample data in the state object. You need to create a similar array of data for you data. initialise state `data : []` and then adter fecthing object just `this.state.data.push({'name': 'xyz', 'id': '123'}); this.setState({data: this.state.data});`

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

It will help you i think.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React Tutorial</title>
    <!-- Not present in the tutorial. Just for basic styling. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" />
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.0/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/jquery@3.1.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/remarkable@1.6.2/dist/remarkable.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">


var UserGist = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {

      username:[],
      companyID:[]
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() 
  {

    var rows = [];

   this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
      var username = [];
      var companyID = [];
      for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) 
      {
            var lastGist = result.posts[i];
            //console.log(result.posts[i]);
            username.push(lastGist.id);
            companyID.push(lastGist.name);
      }
      this.setState({
            username: username,
            companyID: companyID,
      });
     }.bind(this));

  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
    {this.state.companyID.map(function(item, index){
      return    <li>{item} is the company name,              {this.state.username[index]} is the ID</li>
    })}</div>
        );

  }
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <UserGist source="http://localhost/Akshay/REACT/testDataAPI.php?user=2&num=10&format=json" />,
  document.getElementById('content')
); 

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: TypeError: this is undefined
singleList()
render()
browser.min.js%20line%203%20%3E%20Function:52
[36]</ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext()
react.js:6614
[36]</ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponent()
react.js:6641
[36]</ReactCompositeComponentMixin._updateRenderedComponent()

Comment: can you give a description of the error?? line no:???  so that I can have a look.

Comment: not have a look at it. i have edited it. it will work hopefully.