# React is rendering [object object] rather than the JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to render out journal entries on my site with an object (not array) and I am running into an issue, here is my current code

```
  populateJournal(){
const j = Object.values(this.state.journal);
var journalEntries = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++){
    journalEntries+=
      <div>
      <h3>{j[i].title} - {j[i].date}</h3>
      <p>{j[i].entry}</p>
      </div>;

  }

 return(<div>{journalEntries}</div>);
```

}

When i call this function it renders `"<div>[object object]</div>"` and the text between the divs is plain text.

When i change the loop to say "`journalEntries = <div....`" it renders out the last journal entry as expected, but the issue is that it's not actually appending the journal entries with the loop.

ideas?

Comment: Try to put  journalEntries+= " bla bla bla" into quotes or better move it to another function which returns JSX statement

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Instead of a defining `journalEntries` as a string define it as an array and push the JSX elements to the array in order to render, for example:

```
populateJournal() {
  const j = Object.values(this.state.journal);
  var journalEntries = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
    journalEntries.push(
      <div>
        <h3>{j[i].title} - {j[i].date}</h3>
        <p>{j[i].entry}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
     
  return (<div>{journalEntries}</div>);
}
```

When you append to the string, you are not actually appending a string but an object which is incorrect and hence you get `[object Object]`

You can also use map to render your context. See this answer on how to use map:

[REACT JS: Map over an array of objects to render in JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39150326/react-js-data-display-and-array-manipulation/39150569#39150569)

Comment: Thank you that was precisely the issue.

The reason I have not used map is because I can't get it to work with "objects" it only seems to work with arrays... maybe I am just super noob, but am I missing something?

Comment: glad to have helped :)

Comment: Yes map works only with arrays, For objects,, you need to loop over Object.keys(). I will add an link to an example solution to answer the same

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721168/reactunable-to-loop-through-object/43721237#43721237

Comment: thank you, this is starting to make a bit more sense. also thank you for the link, you've been a great help :)

Comment: Glad to have helped :). Also consider upvoting answers on SO which help you, it increases visibilty for other readers

Comment: I have definitely upvoted all these great answers here!

Comment: oh. I can only do that as of today :) only just have enough reputation haha.

Answer (score 7):

Why you don't use from `.map()`, try this:

```
render(){ 
    const j = Object.values(this.state.journal);
    return(
        <div>
           {j.map((item,index) => 
               <div key={index}>
                  <h3>{item.title} - {item.date}</h3>
                  <p>{item.entry}</p>
               </div>
           )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and it worked. That is much cleaner code... I have never gotten map to work on my objects before. This helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need popluateJournal, just use this in render():

```
 render() {
    //const j = Object.values(this.state.journal);
    const j = [{'title':'one','date':'12/03/17','entry':'This is an entry'},
            {'title':'two','date':'14/03/17','entry':'This is another entry'}
        ];

    //inject j as property into Test
    const Test = ({journals}) => (
            <div>
                {journals.map(journal => (
                    <div>
                        <h3>{journal.title} - {journal.date}</h3>
                        <p>{journal.entry}</p>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );

    return (
            <div><Test journals={j}></Test></div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you already have the journal data on state, 
why would you construct the element outside render?
the correct way to do it is to map it directly on render.

```
 populateJournal(){
     const j = Object.values(this.state.journal);
     return(<div>{
       j && j.map((journal,i)=>{
       return  (  <div key={"journal"+i}>
          <h3>{journal.title} - {journal.date}</h3>
          <p>{journal.entry}</p>
          </div>
       })
      }</div>);
}
```

remember to put the "key" on each mapped element.

Comment: for some reason, I was under the impression that you didn't want to do logic inside the render.... 

Thank you, I thought I tried this "map" but it gave me an error of "cannot use object, only array" I will try again

Comment: i thought "var j" was an array? since you are doing an iteration on it? no?

Comment: so it was actually an "object" not an "array"? but I think doing the "Object.values" turns it into an array? I don't really know, but... your code did not work for me...