# JSX within curly braces

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a conditional statement to print a field if it is not null that I want followed by a line break.  This statement exists within a `<div></div>`.  It seems that `<br />` (or any other jsx) cannot be used within `{...}` statements.

What I want to happen is to conditionally print my string and a newline if the condition is met.  Below I will show what is actually happening.

```
<div>
    {this.props.string ? "$" + this.props.string + <br /> : null}
</div>
```

In this case, `<br />` renders as `[object Object]`.

I have also tried

```
<div>
    {this.props.string ? "$" + this.props.string + "\n" : null}
</div>
```

But "\n" is printed literally.

Why is `<br />` being rendered as `[object Object]`?  What do I need to do to achieve my desired result?

This question is different from the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492166/react-is-rendering-object-object-rather-than-the-jsx) in that I am looking for an inline solution rather than having to build an array with a single value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your approaches didn't work for two reasons:

1. `\n` does **not** exist in HTML (JSX).
2. When you use the `+` operator, e.g. `"$" + this.props.string + <br />`, the operands are evaluated from left to right. Because the operation starts with a string (`"$"`) all other operands are treated as strings as well. In your example the `<br/>` (a `React.Node` / `object`) is converted to its string representation (`[object Object]`) and added to the string.

You could use a [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) in combination with [conditional inline rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) to make it work:

```
<div>
    {this.props.string && (
        <>
            {"$" + this.props.string}
            <br />
        </>
    )}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a fragment to wrap the string and a `<br />` tag:

```
<div>
    {this.props.string ? (
      <>
        {this.props.string}
        <br />
      </> 
    ) : null}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
 {
   props.string
   ? <React.Fragment>test<br/></React.Fragment>
   : null
 }
</div>
```