# Getting [object Object] instead of actual object in React JS

Tags: html, reactjs, python-3.x, loops

I am sending the below response from my API to Frontend(React JS)

```
{
      total_changes:
        [attribute: "some field name"
        changed: [{display_value: "test123"}, {display_value: "random val"}]   # display_name is same key for all the upcoming values
        current: []    
        field: "some field name"]
    }
```

**View from Frontend(React JS):**

[image: If we see the image, as per the response getting from API I am displaying the current value and changed value(differences of current(old value) and changed(new value), the issue here is for changed key the value is displaying [object Object] instead of test123, random val.]

If we see the image, as per the response getting from API I am displaying the current value and changed value(differences of current(old value) and changed(new value), the issue here is for **changed** key the value is displaying  [object Object] instead of test123, random val.

In props getting, **changed**:[{"display_value":"test123"}, {"display_value":"random val"}]

**This is my js code:**

```
<div className="inner-sub-row">
<div className="suggested-change">
<p className="suggested-title">{translate('suggestedChange')}:</p>
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: sanitizeHtml(field.get(index).changed) || 'N/A' }} />
</div>
</div>
```

How can I display the actual value instead of [object Object]?(Please ask me if any inputs needed).

Comment: what about this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492166/react-is-rendering-object-object-rather-than-the-jsx

Answer (score 0):

The output is `[object Object]` because you are printing an object.

To access to the single data you have to use a `map` or something similar. One example could be:

```
<div className="inner-sub-row">
   <div className="suggested-change">
      <p className="suggested-title">{translate('suggestedChange')}:</p>
      {
            field.get(index).changed.map(singleValue => 
               <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: sanitizeHtml(singleValue) || 'N/A' }} />
            );
      }
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, what is singleValue? getting singleValue is not defined.

Comment: It is the current element that is being processed in the array. To understand better how map works: [map documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)